# old account access/merge

Tags: support, user-accounts

Please help with a couple old/new account problems:

1. I was active as catpaws https://stackoverflow.com/users/2747300/catpaws until December 2014. I can't login to that account now.
2. I accidentally created two more catpaws accounts: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5144730/catpaws, and https://stackoverflow.com/users/5141350/catpaws
3. Please help me merge these accounts or delete the extraneous ones (in #2) and use the original one (in #1).

Comment: Did you try the automatic merge process through the [contact us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) page? Even if that doesn't work (i.e. automatically merges the accounts), it will alert the Community Managers that can resolve it manually, if needed.

Comment: I just merged these about ten minutes ago based on account flags, so you should be good to go now anyways.

Comment: I see, great, thanks much!